# Extract href attribute url from anchor

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I can't extract the href attribute of anchors from page.. I tried using re library:

```
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
        links.append(link.get('href'))
```

But it doesn't work, i get the error:

```
table_rows = soup.find('table').find_all('tr')[1:]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Can you help me understand better on how exactly to extract them ?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Full code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

DOMAIN_NAME = "https://www.dllr.state.md.us/employment"
BASE_URL = DOMAIN_NAME + '/warn2010.shtml'

def parse_url(url):
    html_source = requests.get(url, verify=False).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')

    data = []

    table_rows = soup.find('table').find_all('tr')[1:]
    for table_row in table_rows:
        table_data = table_row.find_all('td')
        data.append({
            'notice_date': table_data[0].text,
            'naics_code': table_data[1].text,
            'company': table_data[2].text,
            'location': table_data[3].text,
            'wia_code': table_data[4].text,
            'total_employees': table_data[5].text,
            'effective_date': table_data[6].text,
            'type_code': table_data[7].text
        })

    return data

def run_ingestion():
    html_source = requests.get(BASE_URL, verify=False).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')

    for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
        print(link.get('href'))

        url = DOMAIN_NAME + '/' + link.get('href')

        data = parse_url(url)

        for row in data:
            print(row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_ingestion()
```

Comment: Figure out why `soup` is `None` first.

Comment: `soup` isn't `None`, it has stored the content of the page parsed.

Comment: ```soup.find('table')``` is ```None```, please paste all of your code here

Comment: Full code has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your code, you should try this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')
tag = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")})

links = [i["href"] for i in tag]
```

Comment: Could you provide the list of links you get from `for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):` line?

Comment: So, ```['http://www.maryland.gov/', 'http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAF971858A68E4949', ... ,...]``` A problem was fixed because my table had type `None` but now another error appers: ```string indices must be integers``` right here ```url = DOMAIN_NAME + '/' + link['href']```

Comment: According to your code, inside the for loop, after building the url (in the first case, https://www.dllr.state.md.us/employment/http://www.maryland.gov/), you try to scrape that url. Unfortunately, the _specified URL cannot be found_.

Comment: Alright, i forgot to set which `a`'s to be selected. Now everything works fine with your code and it's enough without using re. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As Beautiful Soup documentations says:

> If find() can’t find anything, it returns None

That means, your `soup.find('table')` cannot be found.

Comment: Take a look at the full code added recently, `soup.find('table')` finds the table in page.

Comment: I tried your code on my PC and as I said before ```soup.find('table')``` is None.
```print("Type: %s" % type(table_rows))``` returns ```<type 'NoneType'>```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a more succinct list comprehension where you use an attribute = value selector with starts with ^ operator

```
links = [link['href'] for link in soup.select("a[href^='http:']")]
```